# assign names to each object inside a list using a vector r

Tags: r, list

I have this list:

```
mylist <- list(TRUE, LETTERS[1:3],  1:5)
```

which returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to assign name to each object inside the list using a vector `a<-c("a", "b", "c")`.

Expected output:

```
$a
[1] TRUE

$b
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$c
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
mylist <- list(TRUE, LETTERS[1:3],  1:5)
names(mylist) <- c("a", "b", "c")

mylist
```

Returns:

```
$a
[1] TRUE

$b
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$c
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Or to use the vector `a` you mention, it's the same idea:

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c")
names(mylist) <- a
```